# Simple unit converter and shipment builder

Tags: python, beginner, calculator, unit-conversion

My first python program top to bottom used for work.

First it converts units from imperial to metric and vice versa, then adds the dimensions to a shipment and prints the shipment. When you do a new conversion/addition it adds it to the shipment so I can see what the final shipment is.

I have already done some pythonification of the code but I know it's far from optimal. Please share your advice in how to improve it.

***Edit*** removed brackets around lists when checking 'in'.

```
import sys
import re
counter = 0
shpmnt = {}
volumes = {}
weights = {}

while True:
    #list of words to exit the program
    escape_word = ["exit", "q", "x", "quit", "escape", "no", "n"]
    #list of words to initiate volume calculation
    volume_calc = ["v", "vol", "volume"]

    #list of conversion factors        
    k_to_l = float(2.2046226218)
    l_to_k = float(0.45359237)
    c_to_i = float(0.393701)
    i_to_c = float(2.54)
    f3_to_m3 = float(0.0283168)
    i3_to_m3 = float(0.000016387064)
    c3_to_m3 = float(0.000001)
    i3_to_f3 = float(0.000578704)


    #initial input of conversion #
    num = input("\nEnter number to convert including unit"\
                "\nor v to calculate the last entries volume\n")
    #counter for each carton
    counter += 1

    #determines the action to be taken on input
    if num in escape_word:
        break
    if num in volume_calc:
        total, volumes = vol_calc(volumes, results_list, counter)
        print(f'{total} m3')
        continue
    if not num:
        print("Enter something")
        continue
    #finds continuous digits  
    regex_num = re.findall(r'[\d\.\d]+', num)
    #finds the units by extracting letters only
    unit_reg = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]', num)
    #adds the units to a variable for unit
    if unit_reg:
        unit = unit_reg.group()
    if not unit_reg:
        continue    

    #the list of digits entered and extracted above
    num_list = [float(i) for i in regex_num]

    #function that determines the unit then determines the conversion
    #required to turn it into the opposite unit                        
    def unit_finder(num, unit):

        #list of unit different ways of spelling each    
        kilos = ["kgs", "k", "kg"]
        pounds = ["lbs", "l", "lb", "pounds"]
        centimeters = ["cm", "c", "centimeters"]
        inches = ["in", "i", '"']

        #assigns the conversion factor and unit to variables to be
        #called later on
        if unit in kilos:
            unit = "kgs"
            unit_convert = k_to_l
            return_unit = "lbs"

        if unit in pounds:
            unit = "lbs"
            unit_convert = l_to_k
            return_unit = "kgs"

        if unit in centimeters:
            unit = "cms"
            unit_convert = c_to_i
            return_unit = "inch"

        if unit in inches:
            unit = "inches"
            unit_convert = i_to_c
            return_unit = "cms"
        #returns the variable with the correct factor, unit and the converted unit   
        return return_unit, unit_convert, unit

    #function that does the conversion math then adds each converted
    #number to a new list    
    def calc(return_unit, unit_convert, unit, num_list):
        results_list=[]
        for i in range(len(num_list)):
            results_list.append(round(float(num_list[i] * unit_convert), 1))

        return return_unit, unit, results_list

    #calculates the volume and adds it to a dictionary with carton
    #identifier as the key
    def vol_calc(volumes, results_list, counter):
        total = 1
        for i in range(0, len(results_list)):
            total *= results_list[i]
        total = round(total/1000000, 2)
        volumes.update({counter:total})
        return total, volumes    

    #takes the results list and adds it to a dictionary with carton
    #identifier as the key    
    def add_to_shpmnt(shpmnt, results_list, counter):
        shpmnt.update({counter:results_list})
        return shpmnt

    #function that updates all the ditionaries with the newest 
    #values    
    def cont_prompt_a(shpmnt, volumes, results_list, counter):
        shpmnt = add_to_shpmnt(shpmnt, results_list, counter)
        total, volumes = vol_calc(volumes, results_list, counter)
        return shpmnt, volumes

    #call to function for conversion and unit finder                      
    return_unit, unit_convert, unit = unit_finder(num_list, unit)
    return_unit, unit, results_list = calc(return_unit, unit_convert, unit, num_list)

    #prints the conversion results
    for i in range(len(results_list)):
        print(f'{num_list[i]} {unit} is {results_list[i]} {return_unit}')

    #call to function to add all values to dictionaries
    shpmnt, volumes = cont_prompt_a(shpmnt, volumes, \
                                    results_list, counter)
    #add weight value to a new dictionary
    weight = input("\nEnter the weight: ")
    if not weight:
        continue
    weights.update({counter:weight})
    if weight in escape_word:
        break

    #prints all the dictionaries in a organized fashion
    for key, value in shpmnt.items():
        print(f'\n\tCarton #: {key}')
        print(f'\tVolume: {volumes[key]} m3')
        if weights:
            print(f'\tWeight:  {weights[key]} lbs')
        print(f'\tDims: {shpmnt[key]} cm')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick local improvements:

> redundant conversions:

```
k_to_l = float(2.2046226218)
```

is a useless float conversion when you can do:

```
k_to_l = 2.2046226218
```

> why 2 `if` there?

```
if unit_reg:
    unit = unit_reg.group()
if not unit_reg:
    continue
```

when you can use `else` (since `unit_reg` doesn't change):

```
if unit_reg:
    unit = unit_reg.group()
else:
    continue
```

> use *list comprehensions* and avoid list indices when you can:

```
    results_list=[]
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        results_list.append(round(float(num_list[i] * unit_convert), 1))
```

can be written as

```
results_list = [round(float(value * unit_convert), 1) for value in num_list]
```

> no indices (again):

```
    for i in range(0, len(results_list)):
        total *= results_list[i]
```

rewrite as (no built-in function to perform multiply like `sum` does with `+`, but `reduce` is also overkill) so:

```
    for value in results_list:
        total *= value
```

> *really* avoid indices when you can:

```
#prints the conversion results
for i in range(len(results_list)):
    print(f'{num_list[i]} {unit} is {results_list[i]} {return_unit}')
```

rewritten using `zip` to interlace both lists as 2 variables:

```
for num,result in zip(num_list,results_list):
    print(f'{num} {unit} is {results} {return_unit}')
```

> don't update your dictionaries with a dictionary of 1 element:

```
shpmnt.update({counter:results_list})
```

is better like:

```
shpmnt[counter] = results_list
```

and to conclude, the clunky part with the `if` on units could be better if you built a dictionary with all shortened ways of writing each unit associated to the triplet (unit, conversion function, return type).

Initialize (once) like this:

```
units_dict = {}
kilos = ["kgs", "k", "kg"]
pounds = ["lbs", "l", "lb", "pounds"]
centimeters = ["cm", "c", "centimeters"]
inches = ["in", "i", '"']
for k in kilos:
    units_dict[k] = ("kgs",k_to_l,"lbs")
for p in pounds:
    units_dict[p] = ("lbs",l_to_k,"kgs")
for c in centimeters:
    units_dict[c] = ("cms",c_to_i,"inch")
for i in inches:
    units_dict[i] = ("inches",i_to_c,"cms")
```

Now use in your program in a single line:

```
unit,unit_convert,return_unit = units_dict[unit]
```

the dictionary returns the triplet and unpacks into the left side variables.

Comment: This is awesome. I will be working on all your suggestions today. Thank you!

Comment: Is this correct:                                        
    results_list = [round(float(value * unit_convert), 1) for value in 
    **num_list**]

Comment: good catch. Edited. you're getting the hang of it :)

Comment: The zip function is awesome, didn't know about that one!